# How to manage micrometer connection error in Resilience4j?

Tags: java, influxdb, micrometer, resilience4j

I used the Micrometer in Resilience4j according to the Resilience4j documentation with the address x in the code. The Micrometer monitor service is also Influx. During the load test, we performed all types of tests, except for the situation where we shut down the Influx server. In this case, the Micrometer gives an internal connection error that quickly fills our log file. My question is, is there an event when the monitoring server like Influx is unavailable for any reason, the error can be handled and only the Micrometer is removed and the rest of the system like Resilience4j continues to work?

In the load test with tps 400, when we cut off the micrometer influx monitoring service in Resilience, an unhandled error occurs and the log file becomes very large.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and investigation and using different methods such as events, I finally came to the conclusion that I should reduce the log level of class InfluxDbRegistry so that the volume of the log does not increase.